# Why the button anarchy when 2 line text in android?

Tags: android, xml, button

I am develop in Android , I trying to set the `UI` of `button` by `xml`.

The `btn_corner.xml`(put in `drawable`) is like the following:
This `xml` is use to set `button UI`.

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">      
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />      
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>      
</shape>
```

And the part of `xml` :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/findCameraButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_corners"
            android:text="@string/label_find_camera"
            android:textColor="#00BBFF" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cameraRecordButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_corners"
            android:text="@string/label_camera_record"
            android:textColor="#00BBFF" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cameraSnapshotButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_corners"
            android:text="@string/label_camera_snapshot"
            android:textColor="#00BBFF" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

But it show like the following:

[image]

Why the Button will move down after the button text change to 2 line?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the whole xml of your layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Change your layout of xml like below. This problem is due to layout_weight. I have changed layout_height in parent layout.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/findCameraButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_corners"
        android:text="@string/label_find_camera"
        android:textColor="#00BBFF" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cameraRecordButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_corners"
        android:text="@string/label_camera_record"
        android:textColor="#00BBFF" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cameraSnapshotButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_corners"
        android:text="@string/label_camera_snapshot"
        android:textColor="#00BBFF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have tested the above and it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line:

`android:layout_gravity="top`

It seems to be present only for the 2nd button and may be throwing things off regardless of the label line count.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the Button is restricted to a specif height value and it has to try to fit the Text Specified which is a little big for being wrapped in the Button(either "Camera Record" or "Camera Photo"), So, you have three options:

- making the TextSize a little smaller.
- increasing the Button Height.
- changing the used words(for example make it "Record" and "photo")